# Beamer frametitle unexpected behavior

Tags: beamer, frame-title

In `beamer` if some content follows the frame title in curly brackets, then the content will be also a part of the title. It happens only when the title is given without explicitly calling `\frametitle`.

Is it a bug or a feature? If the latter, why is it good?

See the difference between the three frames.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}\frametitle{Title} 
{content}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Title} %Without calling \frametitle
{content}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Title} %Only 
content
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the `beamer` documentation, the `frame` environment accepts the following arguments:

`\begin{frame}<⟨overlay specification⟩>[<⟨default overlay specification⟩>][⟨options⟩]{⟨title⟩}{⟨subtitle⟩}`

Therefore, `{content}` in your second slide is interpreted as the framesubtitle and

```
\begin{frame}{Title}
{contents}
\end{frame}
```

is actually equivalent to

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title}
\framesubtitle{contents}
\end{frame}
```

To overcome this, you can use the following:

```
\begin{frame}{Title}{}
{content}
\end{frame}
```